# Javascript: location = something inside async function causes it to continue before actually changing location

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

the code:

```
1    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="shipping_method"]', async function () {
2        await sleep(1);
3        $('#button-shipping-method').click();
4        await waitForRequestsDone();
         //sleep(10000); - if I uncomment this - the redirect happens without firing the next click.
5        $('#button-payment-method').click(); 
6        await waitForRequestsDone();
7    });
```

Line 2: mystically I have to use this to get this magic working correctly

Line 3: this guy calls regular synchronous ajax and in case of error exits function with `location = 'some_error_url'`

Line 4: this function is waiting for ajax calls to finish

Line 5: this guy also calls regular synchronous ajax, and in case of error in previous call in line 3 I see that this call also is fired before page is being redirected.

There is pretty big spaghetti-style logic inside those functions triggered by clicks, that's why I'd like to intervene into it as less as possible.

So I sort of understand that javascript `location = 'some_new_url'` does not equal ajax call, so there is nothing to wait, and probably because I have fast enough PC - 2nd request is also fired before actually navigating to new page.

**Question**: how to avoid this behavior and perform redirect right away without continuing code execution?

Those functions:

```
const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

let ajaxWorking = true;

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {ajaxWorking = false;});

async function waitForRequestsDone() {
    ajaxWorking = true;
    let i=0;
    while (ajaxWorking) {await sleep(50); i++; if(i>40) {break;}}
}
```

A snippet of one of those click functions (simplified, another one is the same by functionality):

```
$(document).delegate('#button-shipping-method', 'click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'some_url',
            type: 'post',
            data: some_data,
            success: function (json) {
                if (json['redirect']) {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }
```

Comment: "*regular synchronous ajax*" - uh, *regular* ajax is asynchronous?

Comment: "*in case of error exits function with `location = 'some_error_url'`*" - yeah, that should stop normally stop processing immediately. Can you show us that code, please? It's hard to tell what you are experiencing without a [mcve].

Comment: @Bergi Yeah man, I am completely messed up with what is what in javascript and where is that border where asynchronous becomes synchronous :) I've updated question with short snippet of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling element.click(), don't use anonymous functions and call the handler directly, i.e.:

```
const shippingHandler = () => //Do stuff
$(#button-shipping-method).onClick(shippingHandler)

 $(document).on('click', 'input[name="shipping_method"]', async function () {
    await shippingHandler();
});
```

Then, if shipping handler errors, redirect and never resolve.

Comment: `$(#button-shipping-method).onClick(shippingHandler)` - will this work on dynamically created elements?

Comment: Without knowing the ins and outs of your code, I don't see why it wouldn't work on dynamically created elements. Please bear in mind though, what I've written above is basically pseudo code, and onClick should be changed to however you add event listeners!